# Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, libx265

Im trying to trans code a mp4 file using the following command using a ffmpeg static build

```
./ffmpeg -i /tmp/tools/file_example.mp4 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -c:v libx265 -f dash \
-b:v:0 25M -b:v:1 15M -b:v:2 6M -b:v:3 1M -maxrate 25M -bufsize 1835k -s:v:0 3840x2160 \
-s:v:1 3840x2160 -s:v:2 1920x1080 -s:v:3 1920x1080 -keyint_min 150 -g 150 \ /tmp/tools/example/4k.mpd
```

On executing the command im getting the following exception

```
 ./ffmpeg -i /tmp/tools/file_example.mp4 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -c:v libx265 -f dash -b:v:0 25M -b:v:1 15M -b:v:2 6M -b:v:3 1M -maxrate 25M -bufsize 1835k -s:v:0 3840x2160 -s:v:1 3840x2160 -s:v:2 1920x1080 -s:v:3 1920x1080 -keyint_min 150 -g 150 \ /tmp/tools/example/
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/tools/file_example.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4675 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4486 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-08-07T09:13:36.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:3 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:4 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:5 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:6 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:7 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.0+1-ed72af837053
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 6.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-25000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 1835 / 25000 / 0.750
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=8 deblock sao
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.0+1-ed72af837053
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 6.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(34 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-15000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 1835 / 25000 / 0.750
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=8 deblock sao
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.0+1-ed72af837053
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 6.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4 (High tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-6000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 1835 / 25000 / 0.750
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=6 deblock sao
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.0+1-ed72af837053
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 6.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-4 (High tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(17 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / on / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-1000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 1835 / 25000 / 0.750
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 rskip signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=6 deblock sao
[dash @ 0x5f21000] Opening ' /tmp/tools/example/init-stream0.m4s' for writingtrate=N/A speed=N/A    
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Error initializing output stream 0:7 -- 
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 100.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 

encoded 0 frames
[aac @ 0x5f30d00] Qavg: -nan
[aac @ 0x5f30d00] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 100.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 

encoded 0 frames
[aac @ 0x5f24ac0] Qavg: -nan
[aac @ 0x5f24ac0] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 100.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 

encoded 0 frames
[aac @ 0x5f33ec0] Qavg: -nan
[aac @ 0x5f33ec0] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 100.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% 

encoded 0 frames
[aac @ 0x5f434c0] Qavg: -nan
Conversion failed!
```

ffmpeg -version

```
./ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

Can someone help me to rectify the issue ?

Comment: Remove the slash after `-g 150`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.It worked!. Can you please add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the slash after `-g 150` else ffmpeg will treat the escaped space character as part of the output filename. It will then try to create a file with that path and fail.